# Randomly Shuffle Two CSV Files Independently in Python

Tags: python, csv, random, shuffle

Unfortunately, I do not have much experience in programming, but I want to achieve the following with Python (and I would be really happy when someone would help me doing and understanding this):

I have two csv files, say list1.csv and list2.csv and I want to combine them in a new csv after randomly shuffle them seperately in the following way: Suppose list1.csv has the following structure:

```
Header1 Header2
A       1
B       2
C       3
…       …
```

I want to shuffle the elements of the two columns (but not the headers), but keep the elements in each row together, e.g.:

```
Header1 Header2
B       2
A       1
C       3
…       …
```

For list2.csv I want to do the same thing and it has the very same structure, i.e.:

```
Header3 Header4
a       x1
b       x2
c       x3
…       …
```

In the end I want to glue them together in a new, seperate csv (the individual items in the csv's are stimuli for an experiment) with the following result:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4
B       2       c       x3
C       3       a       x1
A       1       b       x2
…       …       …       …
```

I think, I have to do the following (based on what I googled together):

```
#I actually do not know why I write this :)
import random 

#I guess this activates the import of a csv :)
import csv 

#Import the first csv file and store it in a variable
#I also want to tell Python that I want him to ignore the headers, but later on I need them back somehow :o
list1=list(csv.reader(open('list1.csv', header=None)))
```

As you make have noticed I'm very unfamiliar with this :( I guess I need to learn some Python in the future!

From what I read I think I need to extract the rows and glue them together with `zip()` and then use `random.shuffle()`.

I hope I was clear in what my goals are and I would be really greatful for some help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it.

```
import random

import csv

list1 = list(csv.reader(open('list1.csv')))
list2 = list(csv.reader(open('list2.csv')))
header1, header2 = list1.pop(0), list2.pop(0)
random.shuffle(list1)
random.shuffle(list2)
list1 = [header1]+list1
list2 = [header2]+list2
listout = [list1[i] + list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
outputwriter = csv.writer(open("listout.csv", "wb"))
outputwriter.writerows(listout)
```

Going through line by line:

```
import random
```

imports the random library, which includes helpful functions like random.shuffle. Not sure if you know what libraries are, but basically they add certain functions and or classes which you can use.

```
import csv
```

imports the csv library.

```
list1 = list(csv.reader(open('list1.csv')))
list2 = list(csv.reader(open('list2.csv')))
```

Reads the contents of the two files and puts each row as an element of a list.

```
header1, header2 = list1.pop(0), list2.pop(0)
```

Takes the header, which is the first element of the list, out of the list and stores it for later use.

```
random.shuffle(list1)
random.shuffle(list2)
```

Shuffles the lists into random order.

```
list1 = [header1]+list1
list2 = [header2]+list2
```

Puts the headers back at the front of the list. You can't use += because that will put them at the back of the list. You need to put them in brackets because they are a list, so if you add them directly to the other list, each element of header1 will become an individual element, rather than remain as a list, inside list1, which is what we want because that is the format needed to write the csv.

```
listout = [list1[i] + list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
```

This is a list comprehension which adds each element of list1 with those of list2, concatenating them to form a list with all 4 columns,

```
outputwriter = csv.writer(open("listout.csv", "wb"))
outputwriter.writerows(listout)
```

These open a csv writer on listout.csv, then writes listout to it.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! This does exactly what I want! :* And thank you for the comments! I really appreciate that you help me understand what the lines do!

Answer (score 0):

Just add data from csvs to a single list and then shuffle it

```
>>> import csv, pprint
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> allData = []
>>> 
>>> with open('list1.csv', 'rb') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f)
...     next(reader)
...     for row in reader:
...             allData += [row]
... 
['Header1', 'Header2']
>>> with open('list2.csv', 'rb') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f)
...     next(reader)
...     for row in reader:
...             allData += [row]
... 
['Header3', 'Header4']
>>> shuffle(allData)
>>> pprint.pprint(allData)
[['b', 'x2'], ['a', 'x1'], ['A', '1'], ['B', '2'], ['C', '3'], ['c', 'x3']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I added:

    `import csv

    with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(allData)`

Unfortunately, the headers are gone now and the table looks, for example, like this:


    `A 1
    F 6
    a x1
    b x2
    B 2
    E 5
    e x5
    D 4
    d x4
    C 3
    f x6
    c x3`

Does this stem from the way I wrote it to the csv? (Edit: There should be a linebreak after A 1, after F 6, after  a x1, etc.)

Comment: nop, you are right. when reading csv files `next(reader)` bypassing the first line of each file. so, if you want to keep the headers as normal row like the others comment these two lines of code.